# Process a multidimensional array with a controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am working on symfony 3.1 and I've a little question.
I have a parameter in my file config.yml like that :

```
parameters:
data: [[1,1],[3,8],[12,13]]
```

I know that for take and use it in my controller I need to use :

```
$this->getParameter('data');
```

But how can I do for display the tables in one table like that :

[image]

It's the first time that I use a yml parameter :/

Thank's for your helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Symfony Documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html

In your controller you need something like:

```
$this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
    'my_data' => $this->getParameter('data'),
));
```

and the `index.html.twig` will look something like:

```
{% block body %}
    <table>
        {% for data in my_data %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ data.0 }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.1 }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

**Update:**

To control the `<td>` if there are more or less depending on the array just do another `for` loop like:

```
{% block body %}
    <table>
        {% for data in my_data %}
            <tr>
                {% for data_inner in data %}
                    <td>{{ data_inner }}</td>
                {% endfor %}   
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Oh thanks so much ! But here I can control the columns, how can I control the lines ? Imagine I want to use only one case? Thanks again!

Comment: Ok nice! But If I want to isolate a case ? Imagine I want to do "the first case (1)" + "the second case (1) " on a third collumn

Comment: @MrCarrot in twig a `for`-loop has special variables inside like `loop.index` see here for more information: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html